# undefined constant ParseConfig

Tags: ruby

Actually i'm experimenting with ruby-lint and ruboto to improve my code. ruby-lint says:

> "get.rb: error: line 89, column 14: undefined constant ParseConfig"

On that place i have the marked code:

```
require 'parseconfig'
module PublicanCreatorsGet
 def self.config
    home = Dir.home
    config = ParseConfig.new("#{home}/.publicancreators.cfg") <-------
 end
end
```

But what makes this to a constant? I thought they are UPPERCASED.

Comment: The error really means that the class was not found. Class names are technically constants. By ruby conventions, constants must _begin_ with a capital letter, not necessarily be all capital; classes and modules are not all caps.  http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html

Comment: Thank you very much for clarify :-)

Comment: I cannot duplicate this issue? If I `require 'parseconfig'` I can access the top level constant `ParseConfig` without issue.

Answer (score 0):

A variable whose name begins with an uppercase letter (A-Z) is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby treated class name as constant, if you really want to solve the error you can try following in your module

```
require 'parseconfig'

module PublicanCreatorsGet
  include ParseConfig

   def self.config
       home = Dir.home
       config = ParseConfig.new("#{home}/.publicancreators.cfg")
   end
end
```

Comment: your requires are incorrect `parseconfig` is a gem and is required with `require 'parseconfig'`

Comment: oh my bad, I seems it is an class written by you. I have edited the answer, did this help you a bit?